# Flutter User Record

Tags: database, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

[image]

@ralemos I receive below errors with your code! How can I correct it?

I have a 1000 documents in my firestore database. With a button press user can fetch a random document into a list.

The signedin user can see previous documents in the list and the documents cannot be duplicated. There will be a common database pool but all fetched documents will be user specific.

So my question is how do I keep the fetched documents according to specific user fetched list? Also I would like to know how to prevent to fetch same document from firestore into my list?

Below you could find my current code;

```
class _Page2State extends State<Page2> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
    List<String> myListWithRandomEntries = [];

    Future<void> getPosts(BuildContext context) async {
        QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await Firestore.instance
        .collection('documents')
        .where('index', isEqualTo: Random().nextInt(1001).toString())
        .getDocuments();

        setState(() {
            var docs = querySnapshot.documents[0];
            myListWithRandomEntries.add(docs.data['title']);
        });
    }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
            floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(onPressed: () {
                getPosts(context);
            }),
            backgroundColor: Colors.black,
            body: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: myListWithRandomEntries.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return Card(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                        child: Column(
                            children: <Widget>[
                                Container(
                                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                                    height: 50,
                                    child: Text(
                                    '${myListWithRandomEntries[index]}',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 20.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                    ),
                                ),
                            ],
                        ),
                    );
                }
            ),
        )
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi Sammy! Please familiarise yourself with [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before writing your next one. Enjoy your stay at SO :)

Comment: Ok Diggy :) Thank you!

Comment: Hello Sammy, welcome to SO, here is what I understood so far: you want to have a functionality that fetches a random document from the 1000 that you have and adds it to a list of searched documents per user, you also want to compare to the same list so that the user does not fetch the same document twice, am I correct? It might be helpful for us to answer your question if you shared a snippet of your already existing code or your firestore structure so we can better understand the problem.

Comment: Yes that's what I want to realize. Above you could see my current code! With button press user fetch a random document. But every logged user have its own random fetched list and user can not fetch the same documents if its fetched and added into the list

Comment: @ralemos Hi is there any solution for my request? Thank you :)

Comment: My case is quite urgent guys! Who can help me ? @ralemos

Comment: @ralemos I put the question in my first question with screenshot! Could you pls check?

Comment: @ralemos did u check my post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The are 2 parts to what you want to achieve, first you should create a second collection for users with the following structure:

```
user collection
    uid
    docIds[]
```

With this, everytime you fetch a random item for each user, you also make a write to your user collection, adding the documentId to the docIds array inside your user document, this way you will have a list of all the documents that the user already got.

The second point can be achieved in 2 ways:

- You keep your current random fetch to the firestore, however, this would probably be costly to you database billing if you decide to do a multiple fetches when you get a repeated document, this can be a big problem if the user gets close to the 1000 documents and could also impact performance and also very vulnerable to network issues.
- You fetch all documents store it in memory to a list and get a random document from the in-memory list. This way you only get one read but gets a lot of in-memory processing of lists.

I recommend the second but I understand that this depend on how your app will scale as well, so it's up to you, Following the second option, here is a sample of what your `getPosts()` function could look like:

```
Future<void> getPosts(BuildContext context) async {
    setState(() {
        final uid = await Firebase.auth.currentUser().uid;
        final db = Firestore.instance;
        db.collection('users').where('uid','==', uid).getDocuments().then((userSnapshot){
            var currentUserData = userSnapshot.documents[0].getData();
            db.collection('documents').getDocuments().then((documentsSnapshot){
                var documentsList = documentsSnapshot.documents;
                var found = false;
                while(!found){
                    var elem = documentsList[Random().nextInt(documentsList.length)].getData();
                    if !(currentUserData.docIds.contains(elem.id)){
                            currentUserData.docIds.add(elem.id);
                            Firestore.instance.collection('users').document(uid).updateData(currentUserData);
                            found = true;
                    }
                }
                currentUserData.docIds.foreach((id){
                    for(int i=0;i<documentsList.length;i++) {
                        var docData = documentsList[i].getData()
                        if(docData.id==id) {
                            myListWithRandomEntries.add(docData.title);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                })
            });
        });
    });
}
```

**NOTE**: This is all untested and you might have to adapt it but it will be a good starting point

Comment: Thank you very much  I will try your suggestions as soon as possible

Comment: Hi @ralemos I can keep the data with IndexedStack but when I restart the app all the retrieved data is removing. How can I keep retrieved data from firestore with Sharedpreferences?

Comment: @Sammy_developer This is not related to this question, right? If so, I encourage you to open another question so that the comunity can get more details and help you out on this issue.

Comment: Infact it is related :) I want to keep the retrieved data on phones memory. After user re-open the app all the documents will be shown again!

Comment: From what I understood, this is a completely different functionality from your initial question, I suggest that you open another question, since it will probably take a bit of research to find a solution for what you want to achieve, plus you can share all the details in that way so that the community can reproduce/troubleshoot and help you.

Comment: Ok Thank you Ralemos!

Comment: Could you please check my below post @ralemos

Comment: Why you delete my post ? We are trying to learn!!! @Bhargav Rao

Comment: @Sammy_developer I think whatever you posted should either be edited into your question or posted as a new one, that is why the community deleted it.

Comment: you are not using firebaseAuth for authentication?

Comment: I am using anony. auth of firebase. I use this method https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60005221/flutter-your-cloud-firestore-database-has-insecure-rules

Comment: Thank you! I will try it and give u feedback 

Comment: I still get some errors. I 've update the snapshot at the beginning of my question. Could you pls check?

Comment: any feedback from you?